# Best practice to implement a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have got a mapper class which does a complex mapping of one pojo to another. I made the mapper class a bean and wired it to the service class. I could have made the mapper class a static class as well but I preferred a bean because I felt it better in a testability point of view, I can test the service and mappers independently by mocking the mappers. Indeed it’s also possible to mock the static classes but I will have to use powermock or something similar. Another reason to choose a bean is that for certain mappers I had to use interfaces so that I can choose the mapper implementation based on certain data conditions.

This implementation as a bean has triggered a controversy in my team with suggestions to implement it as a class with static map method or to create new mapper objects every time. And we are trying to figure out what is the best solution. Are there any industry standards being followed. Are there any trade offs with the beans approach? Can it have any impact on the performance of my application? imagine that I have got a hundred such mappers. Below is a simple Skelton of how my service and mappers looks like.

```
@Service 
class CustomerService { @Autowired CustomerMapper customerMapper ...}

@Component 
class CustomerMapper { @Autowired CustomerContactMapper ..
}

interface CustomerContactMapper {}

@Component
class InternalCustomerContactMapper implements CustomerContactMapper {}

@Component
class ExternalCuatomerContactMapper implements CustomerContactMapper {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there can be many opinions, if you want to follow conventions suggested by spring, then you did everything right.

Basically your point of testability is valid although its better to use constructor injection in this case because in the unit test you see exactly what is the required dependency:

```
class CustomerService {
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    public CustomerService(CustomerMapper customerMapper) {
        this.customerMapper = customerMapper;
    }
}
```

*Side note*: if you don't like the "boilerplate" of constructor, you can use Lombok that provides "AllArgsConstructor" anyway.

Now some points regarding the performance:
Spring initializes beans during the startup of the application. If these are simple-to-create classes (classes that do not load a lot of stuff upon creation, don't go to the db and so forth, just plain java objects) than it takes particles of second to initialize them all.

Later you have a regular function call (ok, if you work with interface then its a "virtual" call), but in general it doesn't affect the performance, in other words if the app works slow, the reason is likely to be anywhere else.

Regarding the alternative:

I didn't totally understand what does it mean "implement as a static class", however if you want to create a new mapper every time, this would mean that its not thread safe. In the current implementation the service is a singleton, so there won't be many instances of it, it will be only one instance per application context. However it can be called by many threads simultaneously.

So if you have to create many instances -> the mapper can't be used from many threads. This decision has nothing to do with Spring, its your code and your decision to make it non-thread safe (I'm not saying whether its good or bad, just stating the fact).

Now, if this is the case, then your solution is technically wrong. Spring supports this kind of usage via Provider class + there are other ways to inject prototype into singleton:

```
class CustomerService {
    private final Provider<CustomerMapper> customerMapper;
```

You can read [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton#javax_api) about this method

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your comments. Sorry I was not clear about the other suggestion that came through. What do you think about implementing the mapper as a class with public static method. And the service to call the static method to do the mapping.

Comment: In this case it depends on the implementation of the static method that will have to maintain the state in that method. In addition the testing argument still holds - you won't be able to test service without the mapper. I won't be also able to create mappers based on configuration flavors. Since spring provides all the answers to this use case I would go with spring in this case.